# How to use librte_pmd_pcap of dpdk in our own dpdk app for packet capturing?

Tags: network-programming, intel, libpcap, packet-capture, dpdk

I am  new to DPDK, I'm trying to write my own app, which would capture packets at wire rate.  Can I use the default kernel space libpcap long with dpdk ring and lcore. Or can I use the librte_pmd_pcap which is part of dpdk package.

Librte_pmd_pcap internally uses kernel space libpcap.

And I don't know how to use librte_pmd_pcap in my own dpdk app. 
Can someone help me in using the librte_pmd_pcap in our own dpdk app to capture tcp packets.

*I have tested the testpmd app that comes with the dpdk package, testpmd is working fine. I need your help in writing my own dpdk app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to include the rte_eth_pcap.c to the application code and access the api. And this allowed me to use the -vdev EAL option to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to include the rte_eth_pcap.c to the application code and access the api. And this allowed me to use the -vdev EAL option to my app.

Answer (score 1):

If by "the librte_pmd_pcap" you're referring to [this source file](https://github.com/pktgen/Pktgen-DPDK/blob/master/dpdk/lib/librte_pmd_pcap/rte_eth_pcap.c), it uses libpcap, which is a *user-mode* library; it's not part of the kernel.  It uses kernel-mode mechanisms on the operating systems (plural) that it supports; it uses BPF on *BSD, OS X, and Solaris 11; it uses PF_PACKET sockets on Linux (unless you're on an ancient Linux, in which case it uses SOCK_PACKET sockets); etc..

You can use libpcap directly, which will use the same kernel mechanism that any other code using libpcap does, including the code I linked to.